# Trouble accessing an array in a separate class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am trying to access an element of my array that is in a separate class, world, but I get a cannot find symbol error.  Here is my code:

```
public class Lab9 {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        World world = new World();
        world.world(fiveDim[5][3][4][1][8]) == "white";
    }
```

And then the class, world

```
public class World {
public void world(int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, int dim4, int dim5, String color)
{
    String[][][][][] fiveDim = new String[10][10][10][10][10];
    fiveDim[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4][dim5] = color;
}
}
```

Although not written in the code yet, I want to check if that specific spot in the array is the string "white" and if not, to replace it, but I cannot find a way to check.

Comment: If `fiveDim` a member of `World`? Please share its declaration

Comment: Didn't I declare fiveDim in the class world?
String[][][][][] fiveDim = new String[10][10][10][10][10];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be syntactically correct. But idea and code need many improvements.

```
public class World {
    public String[][][][][] fiveDim = new String[10][10][10][10][10];

public void world(int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, int dim4, int dim5, String color)
{
    fiveDim[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4][dim5] = color;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not following what this change does.

Comment: Never mind, this worked perfectly once I changed the call statement to world.fiveDim[5][3][4][1][8]. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

There's a parenthesis where there should not be:

```
world.world**(**fiveDim[5][3][4][1][8] == "white";
```

Comment: Shouldn't I add a parenthesis at the end rather than take that one away?

Comment: This is the correct syntax:

world.world(fiveDim[5][3][4][1][8]) = "white";

So add the parenthesis at the end and '==' becomes '='